# Why saved_model_cli works and loading saved_model.pb does not?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I received a new Tensorflow Saved Model today (saved_model.pb + variables/) and I'm trying to predict images with it.

I have no clues about input and output but I can use **saved_model_cli show** to get some.

Using **saved_model_cli**, I was able to get prediction for one input image.

`saved_model_cli run --dir /path/to/SavedModels/mymodel --signature_def model_signature --tag_set serve --inputs 'input=/path/to/image/as/numpy/image.npy' --outdir=/tmp/out --overwrite`

I'm trying to load this model in a Python code but I cannot get the same result.
Here is the code I tried :

```
        from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saved_model_pb2
        from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

        with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
            data = compat.as_bytes(f.read())
            sm = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()
            sm.ParseFromString(data)
            if 1 != len(sm.meta_graphs):
                print('More than one graph found. Not sure which to write')
                sys.exit(1)
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def)

        graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph();
        with graph.as_default():
            session = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph)
            with session.as_default():
                output_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/output_tensorname:0')
                image = load('/path/to/numpy/image/image-wxh.npy')
                predictions = self.session.run(output_tensor,{'import/input:0': image})
                print(predictions.shape)
```

When I run this code , I have error messages like

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable conv2d_xx/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d_xx/kernel)

Am I missing something ?

What is the difference with the saved_model_cli ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was a problem with the loading of model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import settings
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from tensorflow.python.framework import convert_to_constants

def get_func_from_saved_model(saved_model_dir):
  saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(
      saved_model_dir, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
  graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures['my_model_signature']
  graph_func = convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2(graph_func)
  return graph_func

export_path='/path/to/saved/model'

graph_func =  get_func_from_saved_model(export_path)

path = '/path/to/image/image.png'
img = Image.open(path)
img.show()

img_data = np.array(img).reshape(1,224,224,1)

y_pred = graph_func(tf.convert_to_tensor(img_data))[0].numpy()
```

y_pred contains the same output image as with **saved_model_cli** script.